# Сбор данных для машинного обучения

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, ресурсы, информация

Есть набор параметров который собирается. Условно 1..n, однако некоторые параметры при сборе собрать не получилось. Для наглядности

```
1; 23; 100; 23;12; 432; 2;4
-; 123; 23; 17;67; 567;45;435
93; -; 324; 131;3; 213; 2; 233
```

Как поступить в таких ситуациях? Отбрасывать всю строку? Заполнять средним значением? Заполнять 0 значением?

Comment: Всё зависит от Вашей задачи. Можно заменять средним, медианой, выбрасывать столбцы, строки и т.п. Вопрос нужно уточнять.

Comment: Как понять в какой ситуации, что приемлемо?

Comment: Например, у Вас может иметься две фичи (x, y). При этом, в одной из них есть 90% пропущенных значений. В другой -- все значения на месте. Для этих фичей выполняется cov(x, y) = 0.8 (по всем значениям, которые не пропущены). Тогда очевидно, что ту, в которой большое количество пропусков, вы можете выкинуть. Если хочется экспериментов, то и в таком случае можно заменить все пропуски на среднее. Можно пропуски сделать отдельным, уникальным значением. Вариантов есть огромное количество, даже если перед глазами имеется задача. Что говорить, если мы говорим о сфёрическом коне в вакууме.